# SQL query INNER JOIN only if all exists

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I have two tables, one contains different recipes and the other one contains the recipes_ingredients (all the ingredients needed for the recipe).

---

```
recipes
-----
id_recipe
name
description
etc...

recipe_ingredients
-----
id_recipe_ingredient
id_recipe
id_ingredient
```

---

Let's say I've chosen only one ingredient (egg for example).

```
SELECT * 
FROM recipes r 
  INNER JOIN recipes_ingredients ri ON r.id_recipe = ri.id_recipe 
WHERE ri.id_ingredient = 1
```

This returns all recipes that contain egg. This is logical, but I want to create a query that returns all recipes that **ONLY** contains egg (boiled eggs for example). Not some recipes that has egg as a part of it.

---

If I choose both egg and milk and create the same query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM recipes r 
  INNER JOIN recipes_ingredients ON r.id_recipe = ri.id_recipe 
WHERE ri.id_ingredient = 1 
  OR ri.id_ingredient = 2
```

I will find omelette, but I will also find all the other recipes that contain eggs and milk.

---

What I want to select is:

- Recipes that contains ONLY egg
- Recipes that contains ONLY egg AND milk

I don't want to select a cake that contains egg, milk, flour and sugar.

---

**Thankful for any answer that might get me in the right direction!**

Comment: WHERE ri.id_ingredient = 1 AND ri.id_ingredient = 2
cannot ever happen.....

You would want WHERE ri.id_ingredient = 1 OR ri.id_ingredient = 2;

and then check that you have 2 distinct rows

Comment: Of course. My bad, I changed it to OR now instead. But it doesn't really answer my question.
If I want to search for all recipes that contains egg and milk I only want to return the ones that ONLY contain egg and milk, omelette for example.

Comment: You can use NOT EXISTS sql clause after where clause to check for any other recipe ingredient. Also, you can check for APPLY operator

Comment: Seems like a use case for exact relational division. Recommend reading https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Count the number of ingredients and the number of matching ingredients, and check that they match. For instance, to retrieve all recipes that contain both ingredient 1 and 2, and only those two ingredients:

```
SELECT id_recipe
FROM recipe_ingredients
GROUP BY id_recipe
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
  AND COUNT(CASE WHEN id_ingredient IN (1, 2) THEN 1 END) = COUNT(*);
```

You could also use `GROUP_CONCAT` to collect the ingredient IDs into a string and do a string comparison:

```
SELECT id_recipe
FROM recipe_ingredients
GROUP BY id_recipe
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(id_ingredient ORDER BY id_ingredient) = '1,2';
```

In the preceding queries, I omitted the full retrieval of the recipe for readability. For completeness, the following query will retrieve the full recipe:

```
SELECT *
FROM recipes JOIN recipe_ingredients USING (id_recipe)
WHERE id_recipe in (
    SELECT id_recipe
    FROM recipe_ingredients
    GROUP BY id_recipe
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
      AND COUNT(CASE WHEN id_ingredient IN (1, 2) THEN 1 END) = COUNT(*)
);
```

While these queries are short and readable, if you have a large number of recipes and/or ingredients, you might run into performance issues. If you do, you might want to add indexes on `id_ingredient` and `id_recipe` and try rewriting the query to

```
SELECT *
FROM recipes JOIN recipe_ingredients USING (id_recipe)
WHERE id_recipe in (
    SELECT i1.id_recipe
    FROM recipe_ingredients i1
      JOIN recipe_ingredients i2
        ON (i1.id_recipe = i2.id_recipe AND i2.id_ingredient = 2)
      LEFT JOIN recipe_ingredients ni
        ON (i1.id_recipe = ni.id_recipe and ni.id_ingredient NOT IN (1, 2))
    WHERE i1.id_ingredient = 1 AND ni.id_ingredient IS NULL
);
```

However, I find this version to be more cumbersome and harder to maintain, and would recommend avoiding it until needed for performance.

Comment: I like this; short and to the point. You could enhance it by putting the inner join to recipes in for him too..

Comment: This looks right to me, I'm gonna check it out. I might run into performance issues since there will be a couple thousand recipes and many different ingredients in the future. I'll save the last query for future use! Thanks alot.

Comment: I just tried it out, it works. I'll mark this one as the solution!

Comment: As I mentioned earlier this one worked as expected. But I now struggle with another part. The recipes_ingredients table also contains the amount of the ingredient (called "type_amount"). How do I add this to my select query? For example if I have 3 eggs and 300 (base units, in this case ML) of milk I'd like to only select  that recipe if my WHERE clause matches both id_ingredient and base_units are >= to type_amount.

Comment: If you need to match multiple attributes, you can rewrite the IN expression to a sequence of predicates OR'ed together: `COUNT(CASE WHEN (id_ingredient = 1 AND type_amount >= 3) OR (id_ingredient = 2 AND type_amount >= 300) THEN 1 END)`

Answer (score 1):

Get the ones with EGG and MILK that only have 2 ingredients and UNION to the ones that have EGG and just one ingredient........

```
SELECT r.Id, COUNT(ri.Id) FROM recipes r                            --GET THE RECIPE ID AND COUNT OF INGREDIENTS
INNER JOIN recipes_ingredients ri ON r.id_recipe = ri.id_recipe     --JOIN RECIPE INGREDIENTS
WHERE 
ri.id_ingredient IN (1,2)                                           --EGGS OR MILK
AND r.id NOT IN (SELECT ri2.id FROM recipes_ingredients ri2 WHERE ri2.id NOT IN (1,2)) --AND JUST EGGSD OR MILK
HAVING COUNT(ri.Id) = 2                                             --AND THERE ARE 2 INGREDIENTS
UNION ALL
SELECT r.Id, COUNT(ri.Id) FROM recipes r                            --GET THE RECIPE ID AND COUNT OF INGREDIENTS
INNER JOIN recipes_ingredients ri ON r.id_recipe = ri.id_recipe     --JOIN RECIPE INGREDIENTS
WHERE 
ri.id_ingredient = 1                                                --EGGS
AND r.id NOT IN (SELECT ri2.id FROM recipes_ingredients ri2 WHERE ri2.id !=1)  --AND JUST EGGS
HAVING COUNT(ri.Id) = 1
```

Comment: `COUNT` will only include the ingredients matching the `WHERE` condition, so your query will not filter out recipes that contain other ingredients.

Answer (score 1):

Query for the individual ingredients and make sure there aren't any more by matching the number of ingredients in the query to the count of ingredients of the recipe.

**EDIT**

Required ingredients are mateched one by one to make sure all of them exist for the recipe in question. If they all exist and the count of ingredients matches there can't be any more nor any less ingredients.

```
select * 
from recipe_table rt
where rt.id_recipe in (select rig.id_recipe
                    from recipe_ingredient_table rig
                    where rig.id_recipe = rt.id_recipe
                      and <ing_id_1> in (select rig2.id_ingredient from recipe_ingredient_table rig2 where rig2.id_recipe = rig.id_recipe)
                      and <ing_id_2> in (select rig2.id_ingredient from recipe_ingredient_table rig2 where rig2.id_recipe = rig.id_recipe)
                      and ...
                      and (select count(*) 
                           from recipe_ingredient_table
                           where id_recipe = rig.id_recipe) = <number of ingredients>
          )
```

Comment: `id_ingredient = <ing_id>` only works for a single ingredient. You'll need to rewrite to either use `id_ingredient IN (...)` or use multiple subqueries, one per ingredient.

Comment: Your modified query will not work correctly. It will return recipes that has the specified number of ingredients and at least one of the target ingredients.

For instance, if there is a recipe that has egg and bread as ingredients, it will be returned even though it shouldn't be, since the `in` clause matches (it has eggs) and the `count` predicate matches (it has two ingredients).

Comment: @markusk Replaced in clause for a one by one check of the ingredients against the ingredients of the recipe.

Comment: Now the query works, except that you need to replace `recipe_table.id_recipe` with `rt.id_recipe` on line 11, since you've aliased the table.

Note that you could simplify your query by lifting all the subqueries up one level and ditch `where rt.id_recipe in ...`.

Answer (score -1):

```
-- 1 egg only
SELECT *
FROM recipes AS r
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT ri.id_recipe, count(*)
    FROM recipes_ingredients AS ri
    WHERE ri.id_recipe = id_recipe 
    AND ri.id_ingredient = 1
    GROUP BY ri.id_recipe
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
)

-- 1 egg only OR 2 milk only OR egg and milk
SELECT *
FROM recipes AS r
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT ri.id_recipe, count(*)
    FROM recipes_ingredients AS ri
    WHERE ri.id_recipe = id_recipe 
    AND ri.id_ingredient IN (1, 2)
    GROUP BY ri.id_recipe
    HAVING COUNT(*) < 3
)

-- both egg and milk only
-- change above SQL: HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: `COUNT` will only include the ingredients matching the `WHERE` condition, so your `EXISTS` subquery will not filter out recipes that contain other ingredients.